# Using SVG Pattern as Background

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

[React-Native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg) supports SVG pattern, however, I am not sure how to apply it...
When I try the minimal example from the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg#pattern), I get a blanc screen, white screen.

```
<View
    style={{paddingTop: 20,
    height: '100%',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
    <Svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 400">
        <Defs>
            <Pattern
                id="TrianglePattern"
                patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                x="0"
                y="0"
                width="100"
                height="100"
                viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                <Path d="M 0 0 L 7 0 L 3.5 7 z" fill="red" stroke="blue" />
            </Pattern>
        </Defs>
    </Svg>
</View>
```

Why is that?

Comment: Yuo need to apply the pattern to something i.e. have a shape whose fill or stroke is the pattern's id.

Answer (score 0):

As @Robert Longson pointed out in a comment below the Q. You need a shape (like a `rect` or `ellipse`) with the `id` given in the `pattern`.

```html
 <Svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 400">
      <Defs>
        <Pattern
          id="TrianglePattern"
          patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          x="0"
          y="0"
          width="100"
          height="100"
          viewBox="0 0 10 10"
        >
          <Path d="M 0 0 L 7 0 L 3.5 7 z" fill="red" stroke="blue" />
        </Pattern>
      </Defs>
      <Rect fill="none" stroke="blue" x="1" y="1" width="798" height="398" />
      <Ellipse
        fill="url(#TrianglePattern)" // make sure this is the id given in the pattern
        stroke="black"
        strokeWidth="5"
        cx="400"
        cy="200"
        rx="350"
        ry="150"
      />
    </Svg>
```

Comment: Its not working in IOS

Comment: It is, I am using it currently :)

Comment: Do you know if it has to be in a <Defs> or that's unimportant?